# In Access, how do I pass a table into a query without it running on every record?

Tags: ms-access

Hello and Thanks for helping. A User has requested functionality to assign a column (Work) to other users by adding names at the end of the column. I currently have a query to collect all necessary row data and a table to store the names. I am trying to add the names table into the existing query. It should look like the below:

row1  name1

row2   name2

row3   name3

What I am getting is this from the query :

row1  name1

row1  name2

row1  name3

How Can I change the query to divvy up the columns based on number of names and columns?

Comment: Can you show us the query you are using right now?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The query contains values from another table filtered by name joined with a count from another query. I just need the names table to link properly, but I am struggling to find how to do that. I have done this before on excel using a stored array of the names and calling them in, but I do not see how i can do something similar on access.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then update your question (edit)! E.g. show sample data, query sql code, [format data as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).